# Filter nested elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nested list with groups and subgroups, and links contained therein.

```js
function filtersearch() {
  var input, filter, ul, tr, search, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("list");
  tr = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    search = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = search.textContent || search.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" class="RxSearchbox" onkeyup="filtersearch()" placeholder="Filter" title="Filter list" type="text">
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="linkgroup1">Group 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="linksubgroup1">Subgroup1</a>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>
              <a href="link1">link1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link2">link2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link3">link3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link4">link4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link5">link5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="linksubgroup2">Subgroup2</a>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>
              <a href="link1">link6</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link2">link7</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link3">link8</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link4">link9</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link5">link10</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="linksubgroup3">Subgroup3</a>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>
              <a href="link1">link11</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link2">link12</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link3">link13</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link4">link14</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link5">link15</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have an input box and am using Javascript to try to filter that list (e.g. if you type in "1", it would only show "1", "10", "11", "12", "13" etc., but it's only doing so on the parent element (i.e. will only show "Group 1") and not the children.

How can I get the script to filter all elements of li, parents and children, not just the parent?

Comment: your question is not very clear. Can you let us know what exactly is expected.

Comment: Your `search` looks for the first element: `search = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];`. You want to loop over those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML structure, the following JS code shall work fine.

P.S. Only unhide_parent() function was needed on top of your code.

```js
function filtersearch() {
    var input, filter, ul, tr, search, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("list");
    tr = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        search = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = search.textContent || search.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            unhide_parent(tr[i])
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

unhide_parent = (ele) => {
    if(ele.parentNode.parentNode.style.display=="none") {
        ele.parentNode.parentNode.style.display='';
        unhide_parent(ele.parentNode.parentNode)
    }
};
```

```html
      <input id="myInput" class="RxSearchbox" onkeyup="filtersearch()" placeholder="Filter" title="Filter list" type="text">
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="linkgroup1">Group 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="linksubgroup1">Subgroup1</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="link1">link1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2">link2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link3">link3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link4">link4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link5">link5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="linksubgroup2">Subgroup2</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="link1">link6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2">link7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link3">link8</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link4">link9</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link5">link10</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="linksubgroup3">Subgroup3</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="link1">link11</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2">link12</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link3">link13</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link4">link14</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link5">link15</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="linkgroup1">Group 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="linksubgroup1">Subgroup-dup-1</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="link1">link-dup-1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2">link-dup-2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link3">link-dup-3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link4">link-dup-4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link5">link-dup-5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="linksubgroup2">Subgroup-dup-2</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="link1">link-dup-6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2">link-dup-7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link3">link-dup-8</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link4">link-dup-9</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link5">link-dup-10</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="linksubgroup3">Subgroup-dup-3</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="link1">link-dup-11</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2">link-dup-12</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link3">link-dup-13</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link4">link-dup-14</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link5">link-dup-15</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by placing a data attribute data-id within each li that corresponds with the link number. Then get all the `.nav li` elements using `querySelectorAll('.nav li')` this will return everyone of the list elements. Then you can iterate over these using a ***forEach*** loop checking the `el.dataset.id` to see if it includes the `input.value`, if it does we have a match.

You can then reference these however you wish, hidden elements you turn visible or highlighting the list-items a tag...

```js
function filtersearch() {  
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.nav li')
  lists.forEach((list, i) => {
    const dataId = list.dataset.id
    dataId.includes(input.value) && input.value !== '' ?
      list.children[0].classList.add('green') :
      list.children[0].classList.remove('green')
  })
}
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" class="RxSearchbox" onkeyup="filtersearch()" placeholder="Filter" title="Filter list" type="text">
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="linkgroup1">Group 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="linksubgroup1">Subgroup1</a>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li data-id="1">
              <a href="link1">link1</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="2">
              <a href="link2">link2</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="3">
              <a href="link3">link3</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="4">
              <a href="link4">link4</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="5">
              <a href="link5">link5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="linksubgroup2">Subgroup2</a>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li data-id="6">
              <a href="link1">link6</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="7">
              <a href="link2">link7</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="8">
              <a href="link3">link8</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="9">
              <a href="link4">link9</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="10">
              <a href="link5">link10</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="linksubgroup3">Subgroup3</a>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li data-id="11">
              <a href="link1">link11</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="12">
              <a href="link2">link12</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="13">
              <a href="link3">link13</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="14">
              <a href="link4">link14</a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="15">
              <a href="link5">link15</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```